# How to rename a column using string from another column in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data <- structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Berry", "Cherry"), `Apr 22` = c(1, 
2, 3), `May 22` = c(4, 5, 6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I am trying to rename the third column in my dataframe (`May 22`) by pasting in the string from my second column. My end goal is to have the third column named "Apr 22 - May 22". Intuitively, I thought that something like this would work

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  rename(paste(colnames(2), "-", colnames(3)) = 3)
```

However this doesn't get me to what I need. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:=` with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  rename(!!paste(colnames(.)[2], "-", colnames(.)[3]) := 3)
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Fruit  `Apr 22` `Apr 22 - May 22`
  <chr>     <dbl>             <dbl>
1 Apple         1                 4
2 Berry         2                 5
3 Cherry        3                 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Base solution:

```
 colnames(data)[3] <- paste( colnames(data)[2:3], collapse="-")
```